# How to work around TuringMachine's lack of a halting mechanism

Tags: list-manipulation

It looks like the `TuringMachine` function doesn't have a halting mechanism. When I say "halting mechanism", I mean something that's built-in to the `TuringMachine` function itself. I'm aware that I can do something like this:

```
FixedPointList[TuringMachine[rule], init]
```

The problem is that advancing the tape history via separate `TuringMachine` calls means that I lose out on retroactive tape padding (which is really useful when `TuringMachine` is running on an infinite tape, as the relevant length isn't known until the run completes).

In other words, instead of this tape history:

```
{0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 1, 1},
{0, 1, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 1, 1}
```

I'm left with:

```
{},
{1, 0},
{1, 1},
{0, 1, 1},
{0, 1, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 1, 1}
```

which doesn't look as nice in `ArrayPlot`.

I'm assuming that my options are:

1. write a function that runs `TuringMachine` via `FixedPointList`, grabs the length of the result, and passes that into a 2nd `TuringMachine` call as the 3rd parameter, or
2. write a function that implements the retroactive array padding somehow (**Edit:** I ended up doing this, but I'm still curious if there's a better way to work around this issue)

Is that it? Or is there an easier solution that I'm missing? At the very least, what would be the simplest way of implementing option #2?

Comment: Have you already seen `PadLeft[]`?

Comment: Wouldn't that only help if the tape head moved in a fixed direction? The problem is knowing how much to pad on each side, I think... the first entry in the tape history could end up being index 50 in a length-100 array, or index 0, or index 99...

Comment: I'm guessing there's a way to do it by iterating backwards through the history and calling `ArrayPad` with successively higher `{m, n}` values based on the tape head location... I was just wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: I fear that `ArrayPad` is what you need. Related: [(225568)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225568/67431)

Comment: I don't know whether this meets your need `IntegerDigits[Range[2^4 - 1], 2, 4]`

Comment: @wuyudi I don't think so (unless I'm misunderstanding you), but thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @Natas Yeah, that's what I thought. I ended up writing a function that fixes up the tape history using ArrayPad, it wasn't too complicated. Was just hoping it wasn't necessary to do that.